# What is the make / model of Vin Diesel's father's car in the original Fast & the Furious movie?

Tags: car

What is the make / model of Vin Diesel's father's car in the original Fast & the Furious movie?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not abut maintenance.

Comment: @tlhingan - We have had ID questions before which are considered on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [1970 Dodge Charger R/T](http://fastandfurious.wikia.com/wiki/1970_Dodge_Charger_R/T)